# Reading date from csv

Tags: python, pandas, date

the date in my CSV is Jun-19.

I want it to read like that when I plot the graph.

```
SalesData= pd.read_csv("C:/Users/navge/Desktop/hyperli/sales model/sales model.csv", delimiter=";")# brings in excel sheet

SalesData['Date']=pd.to_datetime(SalesData['Date'], format="%b/%w")
                                 
                                 
ActualDF= SalesData.dropna() #deals with historical data
ActualDF.head()
print(ActualDF)

reg = LinearRegression()
reg.fit(ActualDF[[ "Date", "Marketing_expenses"]], ActualDF.Sales)
```

I get the following error

> ValueError: time data 'Jan-19' does not match format '%b/%w' (match)

Comment: Change your format from %b/%w to  %b-%d.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your format by `%w{1,3}-%d{1,2}`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like (year is missing):

```
myDate = datetime.strptime("Sep-01", '%b-%d')
print(myDate)
1900-09-01 00:00:00
```